# Linq - Is Exact String in String Array

Tags: c#, linq, umbraco

I'm trying to write a Linq query that loops through a set of Umbraco nodes and checks if it's Document Type Alias is in a string array. I've got something very close:

```
if (allowedDocTypes != null && allowedDocTypes.Length > 0)
{
    allowedDocTypes = allowedDocTypes.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
    nodes = nodes.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias.ContainsAny(allowedDocTypes));
}
```

`allowedDocTypes` is a string array that includes the document types. The first line inside the if statement removes any empty strings from the array. Finally, I'm making use of the `ContainsAny` method to check if the document type alias is in the string array.

This almost works in that it'll check if the document type alias contains any of the string in the string array. However, it works for partial matches as well but I really need exact matches.

For example, the string array has a value of `review` in it. What `ContainsAny` appears to do is pull through all the nodes with a document type alias of `review` but it'll also pull through any with a document type alias of `preview`.

Is there a way to easily change this so that `review` would be an exact match rather than partial?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Not really sure what `ContainsAny` is, is it specific to Umbraco?

Comment: using intersect maybe?

`nodes = nodes.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias.Intersects(allowedDocTypes)).Any();`

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I believe it is Umbraco specific.I think ContainsAny is actually working - I had another issue related to Umbraco which was pulling through the extra nodes.

Answer (score 4):

All you really should have to do is reverse the logic a bit and use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
nodes = nodes.Where(x => allowedDocTypes.Contains(x.DocumentTypeAlias));
```